# Django formset - how to update an object?

Tags: django, django-forms

How can I update an object from a formset using `request.POST`?

Here is my code and my problem is that this always creates a new `PhoneNumber` object. But I want to update the old `PhoneNumber` object.

```
def contact_detail(request, contact_id):
    contact = get_object_or_404(Contact, pk=contact_id)
    phone_number_list = PhoneNumber.objects.filter(contact=contact_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        cform = ContactForm(request.POST, instance=contact)
        #the next line is probably wrong!
        phonenumberformset = PhoneNumberFormSet(request.POST, queryset=phone_number_list)

        if cform.is_valid() and phonenumberformset.is_valid():
            phonenumber_instances = phonenumberformset.save(commit=False)
            for phonenumber in phonenumber_instances:
                phonenumber.contact = contact
                phonenumber.save()

            request.user.message_set.create(message='The contact "%s" was chanced successfully.' % contact.__str__())
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/crm/contacts/?oby=1")
    else:
        cform = ContactForm(instance=contact)
        phonenumberformset = PhoneNumberFormSet(queryset=phone_number_list)

    return render_to_response(
        'crm/contact_detail.html',
        {'cform': cform, 'phonenumberformset': phonenumberformset,},
        context_instance = RequestContext(request),
    )
```

Edit: I create three PhoneNumberForms:

```
PhoneNumberFormSet = modelformset_factory(PhoneNumber, max_num=3, extra=3, exclude=('contact',))
```

Edit: The solution using inlineformset_factory:

```
@login_required
def contact_detail(request, contact_id):
    contact = get_object_or_404(Contact, pk=contact_id)
    PhoneNumberInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Contact, PhoneNumber, max_num=3)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        cform = ContactForm(request.POST, instance=contact)
        classificationformset = ClassificationInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=contact)
        addressformset = AddressInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=contact)
        phonenumberformset = PhoneNumberInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=contact)
        if cform.is_valid() and phonenumberformset.is_valid():
            contact = cform.save()
            phonenumberformset.save()

            request.user.message_set.create(message='The contact "%s" was chanced successfully.' % contact.__str__())
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/crm/contacts/?oby=1")
    else:
        cform = ContactForm(instance=contact)
        phonenumberformset = PhoneNumberInlineFormSet(instance=contact)

return render_to_response(
        'crm/contact_detail.html',
        {'cform': cform, 'phonenumberformset': phonenumberformset,},
        context_instance = RequestContext(request),)
```

This approach even adds a delete checkbox to each inline form. Easy and great.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Rather than use `modelformset_factory`, use `inlineformset_factory` - see [the documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) - sorry, should have pointed you to that initially.

Then you can drop the queryset stuff, since inlineformset_factory takes care of that, and just pass the `instance` argument (which here refers to the *parent model*, ie the `Contact` object). You also won't need to iterate through explicitly setting the contact attribute on save, as again that's taken care of.

Comment: Thanks..I learn a lot today :) I get another error also with this approach: IndexError at /crm/contacts/15/
- list index out of range .. hopefully I get rid of it with inlineformset_factory

Comment: Ok seems to work. I just tried it for the PhoneNumber objects. And wow.. I got a really nice delete checkbox for each inline object.. wuhaa :) But one question: Is there a way to define a max_num of inline objects? Since it always adds three more inlines.

Comment: Ah ok, same solution as for "normal" formsets. max_num=3 or extra=0