# How to write an update view with formset_factory

Tags: django, formset

I love how I can pass an instance to a form and it will populate it on a page. The trouble I am having is with formset_factory. I am trying to use query_set...

```
def classroom_update(request, pk):

    classroom = get_object_or_404(Classroom, pk=pk)
    students = classroom.student_set.all()

    # Empty formset forms should be required
    class RequiredFormSet(BaseFormSet):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(RequiredFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            for form in self.forms:
                form.empty_permitted = False

    #StudentFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Classroom, Student)
    StudentFormSet = formset_factory(StudentForm, max_num=100, formset=RequiredFormSet)

    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...

        classroom_form = ClassroomForm(request.POST)
        student_formset = StudentFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if classroom_form.is_valid() and student_formset.is_valid():
            classroom = classroom_form.save(commit=False)
            classroom.user = request.user
            classroom.save()
            for form in student_formset.forms:
                student = form.save(commit=False)
                student.classroom = classroom
                student.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/') # Redirect to a 'success' page
    else:
        classroom_form = ClassroomForm(instance=classroom)
        student_formset = StudentFormSet(query_set=students)

    # For CSRF protection
    # See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/ 
    c = {'classroom_form': classroom_form,
         'student_formset': student_formset,
        }
    c.update(csrf(request))

    return render_to_response('reports/modify_classroom.html', c)
```

EDIT: Here is the error message...

`formset_factory() got an unexpected keyword argument 'query_set'`

Apparently I don't know how to use query_set...

Comment: What are those errors? Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988968/django-formset-how-to-update-an-object

Comment: Errors related to query_set

Comment: `StudentFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Classroom, Student)` How do I incorporate StudentForm into this?

Comment: @fragles, I posted the error message.